# Convergence to law of large numbers without using borel cantelli lemma

Tags: convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I am studying convergence in probability    ... almost sure , in mean ,
And I have not studied borel cantelli lemma .

Now in most of the answers on such questions this lemma is quoted .

Since it is not in my syllabus , shall I study it or their are other methods without using it?

Please suggest .

I am writing one of the question here

**Que** ) $P(X= -n ) = P(X= n ) = \frac{3}{\pi^2 n^2 } , n =1,2,3,...$

Check whether {$X_n$} follow SLLN , WLLN .

Please solve the above question without using Borel Cantelli lemma.
**Edit :**

Now what i understood from borel cantelli lemma

That is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}P(A_n) < \infty $ Than $P(A_n $ occuring infinit times)  = 0

Now can anyone please help as in how to apply to this question  , **using borel cantelli** ??

Comment: You will have difficulty proving the Strong Law of Large Numbers (almost sure convergence of the mean) without something as difficult as the Borel Cantelli lemma.  The Weak Law does not need it, and the Central Limit Theorem could be shown for example with convergence of the characteristic function

Comment: @henry Okay , so could you suggest a good book to study borel cantelli lemma??

Comment: It is in many places on the web, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279090/can-someone-explain-the-borel-cantelli-lemma